# What is the easiest way to operationalize Python code?

Tags: python-3.x, frontend, data-analysis

I am new to writing Python code. I have currently written a few modules for data analysis projects. The data is queried from AWS Redshift tables and summarized in CSVs and Excel spreadsheets.

At this point I do not want to pass it on other users in the org as I do not want to expose the code.

**Is there an easy way to operationalize the code without exposing it?**

PS: I am in the process of learning front-end development (Flask, HTML, CSS) so users can input data and get results back.

Answer (score 0):

Python programs are almost always shipped as bare source. There *are* ways of compiling Python code into binaries, but this is not a common thing to do and usually I would not recommend it, as it's not as easy as one might expect (which is too bad, really).

That said, you can check out [cx_Freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [Cython](https://cython.org/).

Comment: Thank you! I tried compiling before but the size of my environment made the size of my final executable really large (not ideal at all). I will try and use cx_freeze (or) Cython until I have a front end.